# Setting a minimum value for NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm using NMaximize to find the maximum of a multivariable equation. I know that the maximum should be greater than some minimal value, say 0.00001. How can I force NMaximize to keep searching for a maximum until it finds one that is larger than this minimal value? I should add that currently, the computation ends much sooner than I would expect with some maximum on the order of 10^-11.

Here is the code I am running, the beginning is the set up of all the variables and the maximization with the constraints is at the end. I am trying to make it maximize for numbPart = 20

```
\[Alpha] = .1;
a = 1.;
numbPart = 26;
tvar = Flatten[
   Table[{Subscript[x, i], Subscript[y, i]}, {i, 1, numbPart}]];
var = Flatten[
   Table[{Subscript[x, i], Subscript[y, i]}, {i, 1, numbPart}]];

lagz[n_, m_, z_, zbar_] := 
 1/Sqrt[Pi*a^2*n!*m!]* E^(z*zbar/(2.*a^4)) * (a)^(m + n)*
  D[ E^(-(z*zbar)/a^4), {z, n}, {zbar, m}]
lagnlz[n_, l_, z_, zbar_] := 
 Sqrt[n!/(Pi*a^2*(n + l)!)]* (z/a)^l LaguerreL[n, l, z*zbar/a^2]*
  E^(-z*zbar/(2.*a^2))
lagnlxy[n_, l_, x_, y_] := 
 Sqrt[n!/(Pi*a^2*(n + l)!)]* ((x + I*y)/a)^l LaguerreL[n, 
   l, (x^2 + y^2)/a^2]*E^(-(x^2 + y^2)/(2.*a^2))

MaxEn = 10;
MaxState = Binomial[MaxEn + 1, 2];
nlBasis = {{0, 0}};
For[En = 1, En < MaxEn, En++, 
 instances = 
  FindInstance[2 n + l == En && n + l >= 0 && n >= 0, {n, l}, 
   Integers, En + 1];
 For[iter = 1, iter <= En + 1, iter++,
  nlBasis = Join[nlBasis, {{n, l}} /. instances[[iter]]]
  ]
 ]
nlBasis;
\[CapitalOmega] = .0001;
stateEnergy = 
  Table[2*nlBasis[[i, 1]] + 
    nlBasis[[i, 2]] *(1 - \[CapitalOmega]), {i, 1, MaxState}];
stateEnergy;
lowest = Ordering[stateEnergy, 
  numbPart]; (*gives indices of the lowest n states, whre n = \
numbPart is number of particles*)
lowest;

wavefn[tvar] := 
  Re[Det[Table[ 
       lagnlxy[nlBasis[[lowest[[j]], 1]], nlBasis[[lowest[[j]], 2]], 
        var[[2*i - 1]], var[[2*i]]]
       , {i, 1, numbPart}, {j, 1, numbPart}]]*
     Det[Table[ 
       lagnlxy[nlBasis[[lowest[[j]], 1]], nlBasis[[lowest[[j]], 2]], 
        var[[2*i - 1]], -1*var[[2*i]]]
       , {i, 1, numbPart}, {j, 1, numbPart}]]] /. {a -> 1.};

waveM = Table[ 
   lagnlxy[nlBasis[[lowest[[j]], 1]], nlBasis[[lowest[[j]], 2]], 
    tvar[[2*i - 1]], tvar[[2*i]]]
   , {i, 1, numbPart}, {j, 1, numbPart}];
waveBarM = 
  Table[ lagnlxy[nlBasis[[lowest[[j]], 1]], nlBasis[[lowest[[j]], 2]],
     tvar[[2*i - 1]], -1*tvar[[2*i]]]
   , {i, 1, numbPart}, {j, 1, numbPart}];
detM[var_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Det[waveM /. {tvar -> var}];
detMBar[var_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
  Det[waveBarM /. {tvar -> var}];


SetSystemOptions["EvaluateNumericalFunctionArgument" -> True];
AbsoluteTiming[NMaximize[{Re[detM[var]*detMBar[var]],
   Table[{var[[2*i - 1]], var[[2*i]]}, {i, 1, numbPart}] \[Element] 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 4]  &&
    Reduce[
     Table[var[[2*i - 1]]^2 + var[[2*i]]^2, {i, 1, numbPart}] >= 
       Table[0, {i, 1, numbPart}] && 
      Table[var[[j]], {j, 1, 2 numbPart/2, 2}] >= 
       Table[0, {j, 1, 2 numbPart/2, 2}] &&
      If[Mod[numbPart, 2] == 0, 
        Table[var[[j]], {j, 2 numbPart/2 + 1, 2 numbPart, 2}] ,
        Table[var[[j]], {j, 2 numbPart/2 + 2, 2 numbPart, 2}] ] <=  
       If[Mod[numbPart, 2] == 0, 
        Table[0, {j, 2 numbPart/2 + 1, 2 numbPart, 2}] ,
        Table[0, {j, 2 numbPart/2 + 2, 2 numbPart, 2}] ] &&
      Table[var[[j]], {j, 2, 2 numbPart, 4}] >= 
       Table[0, {j, 2, 2 numbPart, 4}] &&
      If[Mod[numbPart, 2] == 0, 
        Table[var[[j]], {j, 4, 2 numbPart, 4}] ,
        Table[var[[j]], {j, 4, 2 numbPart, 4}] ] <= 
       If[Mod[numbPart, 2] == 0, 
        Table[0, {j, 4, 2 numbPart, 4}] ,
        Table[0, {j, 4, 2 numbPart, 4}] ] ]
   }, var, Method -> "NelderMead"]]
```

The function being maximized is simply "Re[detM[var]*detMBar[var]]"

Comment: You could add a constraint to the optimization: NMaximize[{f,cons},{x,y]}]

Comment: Your posted code does not execute, returning immediately with an error about a mismatch in dimensions in your constraints. Are you sure that this is exactly the same code you are using? If I remove the constraints altogether then it does execute, returning a maximum of `5.75173*10^-65`. Do you have better starting values for the parameters?

Comment: @MarcoB, I just copied and pasted this code into a fresh notebook after restarting Mathematica and it seemed to work fine, i'm not sure why it is giving you an error? I'm not sure if it makes a difference but this is on Mathematica 11.3.

Comment: I have several constraints already, and I tried adding a constraint that was something like "Re[detM[var]*detMBar[var]] >= 0.00001" but it did not allow me to do this. In some separate code, I am using randomly chosen points within a disk of radius 3 as the starting parameters and making it redo the computation until a good maximum is found. I expect the distribution to be something like "numbPart number of particles symmetrically distributed within a circle of radius 3. Something like figure 1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.01036.pdf